# How to match on all 5 digit numbers but skip the first match

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I'm trying to extract all 5 digit numbers in a file name that pertain to Employee numbers. The problem I'm having is that the very first 5 digit number in the file name pertains to the job number. I need to *skip* the first match and continue on after that and match on all 5 digit numbers

```js
var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141";
var empRegex = /(\d{5})/g;
var empNumbers;
empNumbers = str.match(empRegex).toString();
console.log(empNumbers);
```

I need `"12347, 67890, 10112, 13141"`

I'm getting `"12345, 12347, 67890, 10112, 13141"` and haven't been able to find anything that *skips* the first match.

Comment: Your current regex does not match anything because you do not have any `d`s in the `str`

Comment: i just set it up like that as an example. The "str" in this case is actually a file name being passed into a function to gather the employee numbers i'm after. I need to use regex in this case because sometimes the file name could have 10 employee numbers on it and in other cases only have 1 or 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `shift()`:

```js
 

var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141";
var empRegex = /(\d{5})/g;
var empNumbers = str.match(empRegex);
empNumbers.shift();
empNumbers = empNumbers.toString();
console.log(empNumbers);
```

Answer (score 3):

### Solution:

You had a typo in your RegEx. It should've been `\d{5}` not `d{5}`.

Secondly all you had to do to remove the first matched element was to `shift` the array. [`Array.prototype.shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

It's important to note that when you use `shift` the return of `shift` will be the element that's removed, **not** a new or altered array. That's why you must assign your variable to the original Array, with the `shift` method being completed on the array after the assignment.

Simply put you must do this:

```
(empNumbers = str.match(empRegex)).shift();
```

not this:

```
 empNumbers = str.match(empRegex).shift();
```

Since `shift` will alter the array in place, what you end up with is the `array` minus the first matched element.

### Code Snippet:

```js
var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141";
var empRegex = /(\d{5})/g;
var empNumbers;
(empNumbers = str.match(empRegex)).shift();
console.log(empNumbers);
```

---

### Alternatively:

**A Function:**

If you find that this is something you're going to do quite often, it may be in your best interest to create a function that will perform this action for you. In this case it would be best to use something like this:

```js
var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141", empRegex = /(\d{5})/g;

function matchExceptFirst(str, RE) {
let matches = str.match(RE); 
matches.shift();
return matches;
}

var empnumbers = matchExceptFirst(str, empRegex);
console.log(empnumbers);
```

**A Pure Functional Approach:**

It's also worth pointing out that if you are looking to be using the `Functional Paradigm` in which all sources of memory should be treated as immutable and non-changing the above solutions where you mutate the Array would fail this paradigm.

To avoid mutating data and to return a new Array to replace the old you can use the `filter` method of an `Array`([Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) and filter by converting the index value to a Boolean as your predicate. This will remove the first element because `0` is considered `falsy`, but the rest will be placed in a new Array and returned.

```
   let excludeFirstMatch = (str, re) => str.match(re).filter((_,i) => (i));
```

```js
    var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141", empRegex = /(\d{5})/g;
   
   
   let excludeFirstMatch = (str, re) => str.match(re).filter((_,i) => (i));
    

   console.log( 
   excludeFirstMatch(str, empRegex) 
   );
```

---

**Edit:** As @UlysseBN pointed out you can also use `slice`, which is faster and also returns a new array.

```js
var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141", empRegex = /(\d{5})/g;
   
   
   let excludeFirstMatch = (str, re, len = str.length) => str.match(re).slice(1, len);
    

   console.log( 
   excludeFirstMatch(str, empRegex) 
   );
```

Comment: for your _Pure Functional Approach_, I really do not understand why you are using filter instead of slice. IMHO, slice is better designed and understandable for this kind of task. And I guess also faster. Although I didn't run the tests yet.

Comment: @UlysseBN I went ahead and provided more to the answer using `slice`. You're correct - it slipped my mind because I'm used to thinking of `map`,`filter`, etc. as the pure array methods. Either way it'll provide the same result. Thanks for the comment!

Comment: You wouldn't have to bother since I already wrote it [as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55802427/6320039)... However, the shift explanation you gave is pretty neat :)

Answer (score 2):

`How to match on all 5 digit numbers but skip the first match`

This is one way:

```js
var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141";
var empRegex = /(?:^.*?\d{5}.*?)?(\d{5})/g;
var empNumbers = [];
var item;

while (item = empRegex.exec( str ))
    empNumbers.push(item[1]);

// ---------
console.log(empNumbers);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [array.slice](https://mdn.io/array.slice) after the regex match:

```js
var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141";
var empRegex = /(\d{5})/g;
var empNumbers;
empNumbers = str.match(empRegex).slice(1).toString();
//                              ---------
console.log(empNumbers);
```

---

Another approach, if you know that format of this string never changes is to **not use regex at all**:

```js
var str = "01_12345_02_02_2019_12347_67890_10112_13141";
var empNumbers = str.split('_').slice(-4).toString();
console.log(empNumbers);
```

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.

[Coding Horror's blog](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)